# When should an Erlang function return ok?

Tags: erlang

I often see Erlang functions return `ok`, or `{ok, <some value>}`, or `{error, <some problem>}`.

Suppose my function returns an integer N. Should my function return just N, or `{ok, N}`?

Or suppose my function includes the call `io:function("Yada yada")`. Should it return `ok` or nothing at all?

Or suppose I'm making a record or fun. Should I return `{ok, R}` or `(ok, F}`?

Thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a matter of style, but making reasonable choices goes a long way toward making your code more readable and maintainable. Here are some thoughts based on my own preferences and what I see in the standard library:

- If the function can return with both a success and a recoverable failure case, you may want the success case to look like `{ok, _}` or `ok`. Good examples are: `orddict:find/2` and `application:start/1`. We do this so both cases can be easily pattern matched when making the call.
- If the function has only a success case with a meaningful result, then just return the result as there is no need to add additional information. In fact if you were to wrap the result in a tuple, then you can't easily chain calls together e.g. `foo(bar(N))` may not work if `bar/1` returns `{ok, _}`. Good examples are: `lists:nth/2` and `math:cos/1`.
- If the function has only a success case without a meaningful result, the common idiom is to return `ok` or `true` as opposed to whatever the last returned value in the function happened to be. Good examples are: `ets:delete/1` and `io:format/1`.

Comment: An addition I'd like to make is that you should only return `{error, Reason}` if it is meaningful for the user to be able to handle the error. If it is an unrecoverable error, it is better thrown as an exception.

Comment: `lists:nth/1` is not such a good example, because it _does_ have a failure case (which the user should be able to handle).

Comment: This is a valid example because `lists:nth/2` will fail only if it's given invalid input. `math:cos(foo)` will fail in the same way. Both are unrecoverable, and therefore throw an exception. The pattern, as I described it, refers only to recoverable errors (see Adam's comment).

Answer (score 6):

> Suppose my function returns an integer N. Should my function return just N, or {ok, N}?

If there is no possibility of error at all, or any error indicates a programming error, `N`. If there may be a good reason to fail, return `{ok, N}` (and `{error, Reason}` in case of failure).

> Should it return ok or nothing at all?

In Erlang, you *can't* return nothing at all. If you don't have a meaningful return value, `ok` will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a conundrum I find myself in many atimes. The rule of the thumb (atleast my thumb) is that if a function is to be used primarily with other functions (higher order functions like map(), filter() etc..) or if the function is designed to be "purely" functional (no side effects), then I would prefer to NOT return an {ok, _} and simply return the result. Errors in this case must be due to some logical/algorithmic error which should be fixed and the client of the function should be made aware of any such error.

Comment: Perhaps the answer could be expanded a bit further -- I like the direction you are going and think I understand what you are getting at, but perhaps a bit more work needs to go into it to express to newcomers what you mean. Maybe provide a logical condition like: "if the function is *composable* and *pure* -> don't return `ok`; else it should always return `ok` or `{ok, Result}`", and maybe illustrate that in code. In any case, this is indeed a useful concept in many cases.